# Why do you require connection in the open mapping theorem and maximum modulus principle?

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity, holomorphic-functions, analytic-functions

I cannot understand why we require the connection in these two theorems (or at least I've been taught this way, and also in some books you have it).

The first states that every non-constant analytic function defined from an open and connected subset $U$ of $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}$ is open.

The second says that if the norm of an analytic function defined in an open and connected subset $U$ of the complex plane has a real maximum in a point internal to $U$, then the function is constant. I'll try to prove these two theorems without using connection (or maybe I use that without realising).

First, I want to prove that for every  analytic function $f$ defined in an open subset $U$ such that $f(z) \ne 0 \forall z \in U$ and $\forall n$ positive integers, there is an analytic function $g$ such that $f(z)=g(z)^{n}$.(Here the teacher supposed $U$ to be connected or maybe even simply connected, it isn't clear in my notes).

You just have to consider a primitive $F$ of $\frac{f'}{f}$ and than it is easy to verify that $e^{(F(z)-c)/n}$ for some constant $c$ works. The only thing here that I'm not sure about (and it's where I think the problem is) is that I don't know if I can consider that primitive $F$. I don't see why I shouldn't though, as $f$ is uniquely representable by a power series in balls contained in $U$, and so I should also be able to define a primitive of $f$ locally.

Ok, so let's try to prove the open mapping theorem

To prove that, you suppose $0 \in U$, consider an open ball $B$ contained in $U$ and require $f(0)=0$ (it shouldn't change anything, it's just translations). $f(z)=z^{k}g(z)$, where $k$ is the order of $f$, that is the minimum integer for which the coefficent of $z^k$ isn't 0. Then you have $g(z)$ an holomorpic function in $B$ such that $g(0) \ne 0$. By continuity, there is an open neighborhood  where $g$ is never 0. Using the result proven above, I can write $g(z)=(h(z))^{k}$, and so $f(z)=(zh(z))^k$. You can verify that $(zh)'(0) \ne 0$ and then using the inverse function theorem and the fact that $z \to z^k$ is an open mapping, you conclude.

The second theorem is now trivial, as for every point $a$ in the internal part of $U$ you can send an open neighborhood of $a$ in an open neighborhood of $f(a)$, and so  $f(a)$ cannot be a maximum.

I don't see why these proofs shouldn't work, or where I've used unconsiously the connection. thanks for the help.

Comment: You need a simply connected domain for every zero-free $f$ to be an $n^{\text{th}}$ power for all $n$. As for the necessity of connectedness, consider $U = D_1(-2) \cup D_1(2)$ and $f(z) = 0$ on $D_1(-2)$, $f(z) = 1$ on $D_1(2)$. Not constant, not open, $\lvert f\rvert$ has local maxima in the interior.

Comment: Consider the region consisting of two open disks or radius one, with centers far apart.  And the function =1 on one disk, =2 on the other disk.  Try to see what happens in your proof applied to this function.

Comment: @DanielFischer ok, but where does the proof given fail? I know I should consider a simply connected domain for the first result (and I don't see why, however), but since in the other proofs I work with balls, shouldn't it work? (Obviously it doesn't, you gave me a counterexample, but I don't see the error in teh proof)

Comment: This argument based on primitives fails because it is based on being able to draw a path between two points inside the domain. You can't do that in a disconnected domain. Thus the same proof tells you that such a function is constant *on each connected component* but not globally necessarily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> and so I should also be able to define a primitive of $f$ locally.

Yes, *locally*. Every holomorphic function has local primitives. But we need a global primitive of $f'/f$, and the existence of global primitives for all holomorphic functions is equivalent to simple connectedness [of each connected component of the open set]. To get a global primitive, we must be able to choose the local primitives in such a way that any two local primitives agree on the intersection of their domains. If you look at $z \mapsto 1/z$ on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$, and try to piece together local primitives on the unit circle, you will note that when you come around the circle, the local primitives differ by $2\pi i$. There is hence no global primitive.

Your argument for the open mapping theorem assumes that $f$ doesn't vanish identically on a neighbourhood of $0$. If $f(z) = 0$ for all $z$ with $\lvert z\rvert < \varepsilon$, then we cannot write $f(z) = z^kg(z)$ with $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and a non-vanishing $g$. The identity theorem asserts that a holomorphic $f\colon U \to \mathbb{C}$ vanishing on $\{ z : \lvert z\rvert < \varepsilon\}$ is identically zero *on the connected component of $U$ containing* $0$, but if $U$ has more than one connected component, such an $f$ need not be globally constant. If we consider only connected $U$, then being locally constant implies being globally constant, and the arguments work. For disconnected $U$, we don't have the local $\to$ global implication.

Comment: Why is the existence of a global primitive equivalent to simple connection? I try to guess: every differential form $\omega= f(z) dz$ with $f$ holomorphic is closed, and every closed form in a simple connected set is exact, so there is a holomorphic function $F$ such that $F'=f$. is this the reason or there's something else?

Comment: That's one half, simple connectedness implies the existence of global primitives. For the other half, if all $f\in \mathscr{O}(U)$ have a global primitive, then $\frac{1}{z-a}$ has a primitive on $U$ for every $a \in \mathbb{C}\setminus U$, and therefore $$n(\gamma,a) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma} \frac{1}{z-a}\,dz = 0$$ for all cycles $\gamma$ in $U$. But that is the definition of simple connectedness (well, _a_ definition, there are several equivalent ones).

Answer (score 0):

When proving the *Open Mapping Theorem*, in order to use the *Argument Principle*, it's necessary to choose a certain disk with its center at some preimage of an open set's image point, ensuring careful selection of the radius of this disk to guarantee that there is only one preimage point within the disk. This fact relies on the property that the zeros of non-constant holomorphic functions on a connected open set do not accumulate.

As for why this property of zeros not accumulating needs to be on a domain, it's because we establish this property by demonstrating that the zero set, being both open and closed, combined with connectedness, leads to the proof.

And the *Maximum Modulus Principle* is a straightforward corollary of the Open Mapping Theorem, while the *Local Maximum Principle* requires the use of an additional *Identity Theorem*. The Identity Theorem also holds on connected open sets.